# Selenium Chrome driver targeting a label for attribute

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I would be happy if someone can help me explain how I can target this specific `regOption` bar and click it to move on to the test.

I tried to directly tell the driver to use this XPath below.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='regOptions']/div[2]/div[3]/p[1]/label]")).click();
```

Even tried CSS selectors but unfortunately, the driver can't find anything?

Hope someone out there can give me a hint.

[image: Elements]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Hi! How is going?

Comment: Thanks for ur input guys, I figured it out.

Comment: @JohanFredrickLindström, if my answer was helpful -- check a tick near my answer, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("label[for='reg_option_reg-option-individual-membership']")).click();
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a **`<label>`** is a **Label** and it is not supposed to recieve or act over a user `click()`. Hence we need to `click()` somewhere else.

If you want to click on the element with text as **Individual Membership** you can use the following line of code :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("label[@class='col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 regOptionList reg-option-individual-membership regoption-label']//span[@class='col-xs-8 lbg ng-binding']"))).click();
```